# Are arrays with a defined const allowed in C++?

Tags: arrays, compiler-errors

I tried to run the following code with a C++ compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int MAX=10;
int list[MAX];

int main()
{
   int sum =0; 

   for (int i = 0; i<=MAX; ++i){
       list[i]=i; 
       }

    for (int i = 0; i<=MAX; ++i){
        sum=sum+list[i];
        }

    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

But received this error: 
    "integer array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token"

I don't understand why this is an error because I have defined MAX as 10 right before 
    int list[MAX]
so shouldn't it work?

Appreciate any help

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in your `for` loops.  The array `list` has `MAX` elements in the range `list[0]` through `list[MAX-1]`.  But your `for` loop uses the condition `i<=MAX;`.  When `i` is equal to `MAX` the element `list[i]` will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

No compiler error message here, just exactly what the error message says. You haven't included a `const` before your `int MAX` declaration.

Capital letters and never changing the value of `MAX` doesn't mean it's a constant.

Note that some compilers accept having a variable (i.e. `int MAX = 10;` instead of `const int MAX = 10;` for array initialization. Don't rely on this because it shouldn't occur.

If you want to use a variable to initialize an array, you need to use pointers:

```
int size;
cin >> size;

int *list = new int[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why this is an error because I have defined MAX as 10 right before int list[MAX]

You defined `MAX` as 10 but you **didn't** define `MAX` as *constant*.  It's an error because the compiler insists that (in this case) the array bound must be an integer constant.

One way to fix the error is to make `MAX` constant...

```
const int MAX = 10;
int list[MAX];
```

Another way to avoid the error is to move the array off the stack and onto the heap (since the bound of a heap array doesn't have to be constant) …

```
auto list = new int[MAX];
```

… however this changes the type of `list` from `int[10]` to `int *` and also forces you to become responsible for managing the life of list by calling `delete` when appropriate (which can be a non-trivial challenge) …

```
delete [] list;
```

Not deleting `list` correctly can cause memory leaks.

You can avoid the error *and* avoid responsibility for managing the array by using a unique_ptr …

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> list{ new int[MAX] };
```

However many well regarded authorities would argue that using a container like std::vector or std::array would be a better approach.  For example, in **Effective Modern C++** Scott Meyers [says this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch04.html)...

> The existence of std::unique_ptr for arrays should be of only intellectual interest to you, because std::array, std::vector, and std::string are virtually always better data structure choices than raw arrays. About the only situation I can conceive of when a std::unique_ptr would make sense would be when you’re using a C-like API that returns a raw pointer to a heap array that you assume ownership of.

At this point you may be wondering *why* `MAX` has to be constant in your original code.  I'm not a language lawyer but I believe the short answer is *because the C++ Standard says it must be so*.

For insight into why the standard imposes that requirement you could read some of the answers to the question [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/654614)